# How can I generate a SQlite file?

Tags: sqlite, file, ubuntu, database-connection, metabase

I want to connect Sqlite to Metabase, however, Metabase asks for a .sqlite file to make the connection.

I created a database using the command line and with Sqlite Browser. It creates the regular files (.db, journal) but I can't find any .sqlite file.

I have already exported as .SQL and it didn't work.

How can I generate this sqlite file?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I just needed to change the extension .db to .sqlite, the source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite.

```
Filename extension  
.sqlite3, .sqlite, .db
```

Metabase does not support uploading files, so I had to copy the database file to where Metabase is downloaded. When I tried to make the connection I just wrote the path as follows: ./file.sqlite. Source: https://discourse.metabase.com/t/having-trouble-with-uploading-sqlite-db-in-metabase-web-app/16725